# PowerShell: External Command Output to Internal Command

Tags: windows, powershell, command, external, internals

I want to run these two commands in PowerShell in conjunction, and use the output of dir as the path in Get-ChildItem

`cmd /r dir /b/s/a/t screenshot_37.png; powershell -command "& {Get-ChildItem "dir output" -recurse -force}"`

Can I receive some insight into how this is possible?

(Context: I'm conducting searches of specific files, and want to know their attributes if found)

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you're calling this from PowerShell, you don't need to call [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) to run `Get-ChildItem`: just invoke the latter directly, which avoids the costly creation of a PowerShell *child process*.

  - If you *were* to solve this via `cmd.exe`'s `dir` command (see next point for how to avoid that), you'd need:

    ```bash
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -LiteralPath (
      cmd /c dir /b /s /a screenshot_37.png
    ) | Select FullName, Attributes
    ```
  - Note that I'm using `/c` with `cmd.exe` (`/r` is a rarely seen alias that exists for backward compatibility) and that I've removed `dir`'s `/t` option, which has no effect due to use of `/b`.
- More fundamentally, a single `Get-ChildItem` call should suffice - no need for `cmd.exe`'s internal `dir` command:

  ```bash
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Filter screenshot_37.png |
    Select FullName, Attributes
  ```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your purpose simply capture the output of the `dir` command and store it in a `variable`. Then, use that variable in `Get-ChildItem`. Something like:

```
$dirOutput = cmd /r dir /b/s/a/t screenshot_37.png
powershell -command "& {Get-ChildItem $dirOutput -RF}"
```

**CAVEAT:**  If `$dirOutput` contains multiple paths, they would be passed as individual positional arguments, which would break the `Get-ChildItem` syntax.

**Another Way:**

You could also directly use `Get-ChildItem` to search for a specific file and get its attributes.

```bash
$file = "screenshot_37.png"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Filter $file -RF
$items | Format-List *
```